# Spawn fix count of subprocesses until end -python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, subprocess

i want to iterate through an array with constant X for example starting(50) subprocesses. As soon as one or 1/50 is finished a new process should be started and until the end of array (10000 data sets) 50 processes should run at the same time constant.

example code

```
import subprocess
import psutil
MAXPROCESSES = 50
cmdData =  ['data1','data2','dataX...',] #lenght of 10000+
ls =[]

# in this example they spawn len(cmdData) as subprocees not MAXPROCCESES, (CPU KILLER)
for data in cmdData:
    cmdString= 'sudo python3 ./mypythonscript --data ' + data
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmdString, shell=True, stdin=None, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE,close_fds=False)
    ls.append(psutil.Process(proc.pid))
gone, alive = psutil.wait_procs(ls, None, callback) # callback unused
```

i have already tried to spawn a new one in the callback when a process ends, that would be from a subprocess of the subprocess and as soon as the parent process ends it terminate.

Any ideas?

Comment: A [multiprocessing `Pool`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=multiprocessing#multiprocessing.pool.Pool) could probably help.

Comment: Why do you use `sudo` to run the subprocess?

Comment: ´sudo´ is irrelevant, i will test multiprocessing Pool